# Every Open Set is a Borel Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know this should be simple but I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around it. I also want to prove that every closed set is a borel set but I believe I'll have to use the original proof in my title to prove it.

Comment: What is your definition of a Borel set?

Comment: @Unit  In a topological space, the σ - algebra generated by the open sets is
called the Borel σ - algebra, its members are called Borel sets. I'm assuming I just need to prove that the open sets satisfy the three properties of a sigma algebra?

Comment: A $\sigma$-algebra generated by a class $C$ of sets contains all the sets in that class!

Comment: The open sets don't satisfy the properties. But "the $\sigma$-algebra generated by ..." means "the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras which contain ...". So automatically the Borel sets contain the open sets under that definition.

Comment: So is this wording correct: If we allow $A\in S$ (where $A$ is open) and let $F(S)$ be the collection of subsets of $S$ which create the sigma algebra, we can say that because $A\in S$, we have $A\in F(S)$ and thus any open set is a borel set?

Comment: How about this: let $\mathscr{U}$ be the collection of all open sets from your topology, and denote by $\sigma(\mathscr{U})$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr{U}$ (i.e., the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathscr{U}$). This is, by definition, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra arising from your topology.

Comment: How would I use this to go by proving that every finite union of borel sets is a borel set?

Comment: Well, if you know that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra, it's automatically closed under countable unions, and hence finite ones.

Comment: @sourisse That is what I figured and wrote. I'm assuming for countable unions it is the same.

Comment: @H5159 To show that it is closed under finite unions just note that $\emptyset$ is a set in **every $\sigma$-algebra** meaning that you can write $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i =\bigcup_{i=1}^{N}A_i$ if you let $A_i = \emptyset$ for $ N \leq i$. A similar conclusion can be had with intersections and $A_i = X$.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your comments it seems like you might have a misunderstanding as to what algebra generated by a set means. So let's start from the here:

> Let $\Omega$ be an $\sigma$-algebra of a set X then it is defined to be a
> collection of subsets of X with the following propreties:
>
> 1. $X,\emptyset\in \Omega$
> 2. If $A   \in \Omega$ then $X-A\in \Omega$
> 3. If $A_i \in \Omega$ then $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i, \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \in \Omega$

If we are talking about the **$\sigma$-algebra generated by a **collection** $\tau$** (any collection of subsets of X) then we are talking about

$$\Omega_\tau = \bigcap_{\Omega\in C(\tau)} \Omega$$

where $$C(\tau)= \{\Omega \text{ }|\text{ } \tau \subseteq \Omega \text{ and } \Omega \text{ is a } \sigma \text{-algebra}\}$$ is the collection of all $\sigma$-algebra of X that **contain $\tau$**.

Two things to note about this collection.

1. It is a $\sigma$-algebra
2. That the way it is defined implies that
   $$\tau \subseteq \Omega\subseteq \Omega_\tau$$
   Thus, almost by definition, every $\sigma$-algebra generated by a collection $\tau$ contains all sets in $\tau$.

Notes:

- **Borel algebras are just a special case of this generated $\sigma$-algebras** where the collection $\tau$ is made to be the topology of X.
- Another way of thinking about the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau$ is to think of it as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\tau$

Example:

$$X = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$$

$$\tau = \{ \{1\} \}$$

$$\Omega_\tau = \{ X,\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3,4,5\}\}$$